# PrimeFaces: how to make the theme dynamic

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I need to make the theme dynamic by the different users, currently, I find the guide in http://www.developer.am/primefaces/?page=Applying%20a%20Theme

It says: 
In case you’d like to make the theme dynamic, define an EL expression as the param value.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>#{loggedInUser.preferences.theme}</param-value>
</context-param>
```

In my understanding, the theme will be changed by the different users, right? Even I change the theme in preferences for the user, I have no need to restart the middleware, the theme will be changed at once, right?

Please guide me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be expecting that the EL expression is evaluated at the moment the `web.xml` is parsed. This is not true. Instead, all PrimeFaces gets from the `web.xml` init param is a `String` representing an EL expression like so:

```
String themeExpression = "#{loggedInUser.preferences.theme}";
```

Then, PrimeFaces is programmatically evaluating it on every HTTP request like follows in order to get the actual value:

```
String theme = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, themeExpression, String.class);
```

In effects, it's request scoped and not application scoped as you seemed to expect. The evaluated property can in turn however just be a property of a session scoped bean.

Comment: I have a similar problem. Please tell me how to pass the EL expression correctly. When the application loads this error occurs : "Error loading theme, cannot find "theme.css" resource of "primefaces-[Ljava.lang.String;@6add1c32" library"

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You just need a bean that will return the users's theme name as a string.